# How do you set hover using Chrome Dev Tools on pseudo elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging the Bootstrap Tabs module and the application using the Tab module puts all it's color changes in the the li:hover::before element. Firefox doesn't separate out the ::before from the DOM element but Chrome does. On a regular DOM element, say a, I can right click to bring up a menu to select hover or click the pin on the right side to select hover

[Picture of menu with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVqwE.png)
[Picture of right side of dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRmGy.png)

When I right click a ::before in the Elements window or try to select hover on the right side of dev tools windows, I can't.

Is there a way to create a hover action on a pseudo element?

Comment: Right click on `parent` and select `:hover` option. This will automatically set hover on pseudo element too.

Comment: Set the hover properties like this: `parent:hover::before` or `parent:hover::after`

Comment: Syed, Perfect answer - thank you. Is your second answer a different method? If so, how do I set those properties? Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `:hover` can be applied directly to a pseudo-element. The [Selectors Level 3 specification states](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements):

> Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it must appear after the sequence of simple selectors that represents the subjects of the selector.

I may be wrong, but I believe pseudo-classes (like `:hover`) are part of the *subjects of the selector*. This itself means that specifying a pseudo-class *after* a pseudo-element is invalid.

This in turn means that it isn't possible to apply `:hover` styling specifically on the pseudo-element, however as others have stated in the comments you can do this on the element they belong to instead.

```css
*::before:hover {
  /* This markup is INVALID as pseudo-class selectors
   * cannot be placed after pseudo-element selectors.
   */
}

*:hover::before {
  /* This would apply styling to the pseudo-element
   * when the containing element is hovered over.
   */
}
```

Comment: Selectors 4 states that *the :hover pseudo-class can apply to any pseudo-element* and *a pseudo-element may be immediately followed by any combination of the user action pseudo-classes* (`:hover`, `:active`, `:focus` & co). But it does not work in any browser, which is weird because the browser compat table on MDN has a line "Pseudo-element support" with versions that are a few years old for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above states, it is not possible to directly apply `:hover` on pseudo element. But there's a work around and it can be made possible using `jQuery`. **For testing purpose** you can define a separate `CSS` class for `element:hover::before` add a `button` and apply that class to element on button click.

**HTML:**

```
<p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
<input type="button" id="btnFoo" value="Apply Hover On Before"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
p:before{
  content: 'B4';
}
p.foo::before{
  color: red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#btnFoo").click(function () {
    $("p").toggleClass("bar");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gyuLgdpv/)